Difference between Probability and Possibility in Fuzzy Logic
I'm trying to learn non-classical logic variants.
Came across the notion pvq = min(V(p), V(q)) where p and q has truth values between the range [0,1].
So far so good.
Then I puzzled my mind with this example I came up:
A coin is flipped, heads is p, tails is q.
p = 0.5 and q = 0.5
pvq = min(V(p), V(q)) = min(0.5, 0.5) = 0.5
So, according to fuzzy logic, having tails or heads as a result of a coin flip is 0.5.
EXCUSE ME?
We know it will be either heads or tails in the end, so the result should have been 1.0 instead of 0.5.
Then I came across the difference between possibility and probability. I'm not going to try to define them, because I still haven't understood it fully (hence this question).
If I'm not mistaken, in my example, heads and tails have the possibility of 1, where they have the probability 0.5. So my example is better revised as:
A coin is flipped, heads is p, tails is q.
p = 1 and q = 1
pvq = min(V(p), V(q)) = min(1, 1) = 1.
Ok, but then I have a follow-up question, what does it mean to have 0.8 possibility?
How it is different than probability?
I'm super confused about this, any help is appreciated.
Feel free to correct me if any of the things I stated above is erroneous.

See Fuzzy Logic and more specifically to the question: Fuzzy Logic and Probability.
In a nutshell:

FL tries to understand the concept of vagueness while Probability main concern is with events: to check whether the events will occur or not.

FL captures the meaning of partial truth while Probability captures partial knowledge.



thanks a lot for the resources!

@ÖzgünÖZERK you are welcome :-)
